# Is there a range for an isolation transformer's common mode rejection frequency?

Tags: transformer, isolation

Below shows use of an isolation transformer in a system:

[image]

(taken from [this site](http://www.sacthailand.com/transformer_blitz.html))

At C(right after the isolation transformer) the waveform is cleaner comparing to A and B.

What frequency of interference can an isolation transformer attenuate in general? I there a lower limit for the frequencies it can suppress. I know that EMI filters can choke down to around 10 kHz not less than that in general.

But how about an typical 1:1 isolation transformer? Is there a freq. range it can suppress for common mode noise?

I'm also wondering whether transformers can be used to cancel harmonics of mains frequency like 3rd harmonic.

Comment: The CMR depends upon the electrostatic shields performance at high frequencies.

Comment: well everything depends on everything, but there must be a general range in practice like in EMI filters.. 1:1 isolation transformers for AC power. im mostly wondering the lower freq. limit like 150Hz .